# Laravel $fillable not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following [videos tutorial from laracast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtNdKvkziaU&list=PLqburtDcEYifkSZ0IbhAd4qa2NIiNfb5K).  I got something wrong when I'm trying to input form at the 10th episode. My $fillable variable is not working:

```
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Article extends Model
{
protected $fillable=[
    'title','body','published_at'
];
}
```

When I send the data without the published_at field the data is still inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fillable indicates the attributes that are allowed to be mass assigned using methods on the model like `fill()`. It does not define whether the attribute is required. You will need to create proper validation rules for that.

the provided [lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7m_F2uw384k&list=PLqburtDcEYifkSZ0IbhAd4qa2NIiNfb5K&index=12) indicates how to use validation and prevent insertion into the database based on the validation rules.

Comment: Thanks!! I think I begin to understand this thing.